# error show two different images in angular component

Tags: angular, image

I have a upload component I upload two images but the second image is the first one, in object the name of two images are difference here it is not the bug and when I upload the first image the second change with the first one but if I upload the second image, the image in component doesn't update.

update.component.html

```
 <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="" *ngIf="!imgURL; else noimage">
                <img class="img-list" src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + 'no-image.png'  }}" alt="">
            </div>
            <ng-template #noimage>
                <img class="img-list" src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + imgURL }}" alt="">
            </ng-template>
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Imagen1</label>
            <angular-file-uploader [config]="afuConfig" (ApiResponse)="upload1($event)">
            </angular-file-uploader>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="" *ngIf="!imgURL2; else noimage">
                <img class="img-list" src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + 'no-image.png'  }}" alt="">
            </div>
            <ng-template #noimage2>
                <img class="img-list" src="{{ url + ' avatar2/ ' + imgURL2 }}" alt=" ">
            </ng-template>
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label ">Imagen2</label>
            <angular-file-uploader [config]="afuConfig2 " (ApiResponse)="upload2($event) ">
            </angular-file-uploader>
        </div>
```

update.component.ts

```
upload1(data)
    {
      

      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params =>
        {
          console.log(params);
          console.log(params.id);
          let id = params['id'];
          this.room._id = id;
          console.log(this.room._id);
          this.room.image1 =  data.body.image1;
          console.log(this.room.image1);
          this.roomservice.saveImg(this.room._id,this.room.image1).subscribe(
            response =>
              {
                //this.room.image1;
                this.getRoom();    
                
              },
              error =>
              {
                console.log(error);
              }
      
          );
  
        }); 
    }
    upload2(data)
    {
      

      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params =>
        {
        
          let id = params['id'];
          
          this.room._id = id;
          this.room.image2 =  data.body.image2;
          console.log(this.room.image2);
          this.roomservice.saveImg2(this.room._id,this.room.image2).subscribe(
            response =>
              {
                //this.room.image1;
                this.getRoom();    
                
              },
              error =>
              {
                console.log(error);
              }
      
          );
  
        }); 
    }
```

I don't get any errors in console I think that the backend works the image are uploaded and the object get diferent name in each image property. I don't know if the error it's in angular html.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div class="" *ngIf="!imgURL2; else noimage">
```

not sure if this is the source of the mistake or just a typo, but I think you meant to write

```
 <div class="" *ngIf="!imgURL2; else noimage2">
```

otherwise, if you have no image, it will both reference the same thing

Comment: pmo1948 you are right that is part of the bug but now the image doesnt exist